# CSS text shadow with perspective

Tags: css, text, shadow

I want to achieve a shadow effect where it looks like the bottom of the text is touching the floor and shadow is cast behind it. Something like the perspective box in this [post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/) or the shadows in this image

[image: Shadows]
<sub>(source: [psd-dude.com](http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/create-a-text-shadow-in-photoshop/text-shadow.jpg))</sub>

I only need the shadow to be going in one direction.

Is there a pure CSS solution? Is there a solution at all? I've seen it done with boxes, but not text. The image above was made with Photoshop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with CSS transforms and perspectives:

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#shadow {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 50px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#shadow::after {
  content: 'p Shadow q';
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0.5) rotateX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow">p Shadow q</div>
```

The bottom of the shadow does not seem to completely coincide with the bottom of the text, that's because the baseline is a bit higher. Otherwise it would be bad for characters like `g` `j` `p` `q` `y`.

If you don't want this space, you can reduce the line-height.

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
#shadow {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  perspective: 50px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}
#shadow::after {
  content: 'p Shadow q';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0.5) rotateX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow">p Shadow q</div>
```

I hard-coded the shadow text in the pseudo-element. It would be desirable to avoid this, and let it use the same text as the element. That's possible with an [`element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) background, only supported by Firefox.

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#shadow {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 50px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#shadow::after {
  content: '';
  background: -moz-element(#shadow);
  background: element(#shadow);
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0.5) rotateX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow">p Shadow q</div>
```

Comment: Good answer ... And such a pity that the background: element() is in a dead road

Comment: Used most of your answer. Here is what you helped create: [giphy](https://giphy.com/gifs/hzU3dwV4Ec5Fu) [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/hzU3dwV4Ec5Fu/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 2):

I thought about a solution where I add an `:after`-Element to each letter, with `content: "T"` for example for the letter *T*. Then make the content itself invisible and just use the `text-shadow` property on `:after`-Element, which we can rotate via `text-transform: rotateX(70deg)`.

[I made a draft on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5bk9anr/3/).

[image]

Comment: Hint: if there is no need to style the shadow of each letter individually you could also use only one after-element with the whole text as content.